# Update db field based on array of values

Tags: php, mysql

i need to run a sql query to do some database updates.

```
$members = "120,238,93,123,1";
```

and then i need to run a sql query like :

```
$DB->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "members SET lastvisit=$lastvisit WHERE member_id=$members_id");
```

what i am trying to do is to run the db update for each of the members id`s that i specify at the start of my file.
guess i need to explode the $members and do a for clause or something but not sure how its supposed to be

Comment: Are you familiar with MySQL's [`IN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator?

Comment: You are making it a bit too easy to do SQL injections. I think you should read about them.

Comment: @Patrick: You are making assumptions about the source (and escaping) of `$lastvisit` and `$members`, which are not shown in the question.

Comment: @eggyal true, but I think it would still be better to really use prepared statements as a good practice, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: @Patrick: I don't disagree, but that's not what your previous comment said.

Comment: @eggyal Oke, sorry, indeed I stated it wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$DB->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "members SET lastvisit=$lastvisit WHERE member_id IN (120,238,93,123,1) ");
```

Comment: does the IN function work as an exact match for the values ?
for example for id 93 in my database i can have ID`s like 2393 or 193.

Comment: it is exact matches. WHERE member_id = 120 OR member_id = 238..etc